# Update/Append to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like so:

```
x = {'age': 23,
     'channel': ['a'],
     'name': 'Test',
     'source': {'data': [1, 2]}}
```

and a similar one like:

```
y = {'age': 23,
     'channel': ['c'],
     'name': 'Test',
     'source': {'data': [3, 4], 'no': 'xyz'}}
```

if I used this `x.update(y)` I would lose `'channel'` previous info for example.. How can I append the values when they are different and add keys/values when they are not already in the dictionary?

End result should be:

```
{'age': 23,
 'channel': ['a', 'c'],
 'name': 'Test',
 'source': {'data': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'no': 'xyz'}}
```

I came close with this:

```
for a,b in y.iteritems():
    try:
        x[a] = x[a] + y[a]
    except:
        x[a] = y[a]
```

but it failed when it found a dictionary inside of the dictionary.

Comment: It's unclear what you'd like to do with plain strings. For example, if `x['name'] == 'test1'` and `y['name'] == 'test2'`, what you'd like to be the result? `test1`, `test2` or `test1test2`? Or, for that matter, with integers/floats.

Comment: @PavelGurkov if the key/val is the same: ignore

Comment: But the key/val isn't the same there.

Comment: If key equal = append value if different, if key different = add key and val

Comment: So once again to clarify. What means append when applied to strings?  if `x['name'] == 'test1'` and `y['name'] == 'test2'`, result is `'test1test2'`? if `x['age'] == 10` and `y['age'] == 11`, result is `21`?

Comment: To really do something like this, you need to first define what to do for every combination of types of values. i.e. if `x[key]` is a `list` and `y[key]` is a `dict`, if `x[key]` is a `set` and `y[key]` is a `dict`, etc.

Comment: @martineau, that's the problem with this question. It's not clear what the result should be. Judging from the question statement, it has some set of rules, but they're mostly implied.
And chances are, this is gonna turn into an ugly recursive rollercoaster of `if isinstance()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement seems a bit vague, but you can do what you want with a recursive function like the following. (To the point I understood your requirements, you can't append *sets* to *dicts* right ? or the likes of these cases)

```
x = {'age': 23,
     'channel': ['a'],
     'name': 'Test',
     'source': {'data': [1, 2], 'no': 'jj'}}

y = {'age': 23,
     'channel': ['c'],
     'name': 'Test',
     'source': {'data': [3, 4], 'no': 'xyz'}}


def deep_update(x, y):
    for key in y.keys():
        if key not in x:
            x.update({key: y[key]})
        elif x[key] != y[key]:
            if isinstance(x[key], dict):
                x.update({key: deep_update(x[key], y[key])})
            else:
                x.update({key: list(set(x[key] + y[key]))})
    return x


print deep_update(x, y)
```

> {'source': {'data': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'no': 'jjxyz'}, 'age': 23, 'name': 'Test', 'channel': ['a', 'c']}

Comment: It's still duplicating on the list =/

Comment: @Onilol It won't append two lists that are the same, wasn't that your requirement ? x = {'source': {'data': [3, 4]}}, y = {'source': {'data': [3, 4]} would yield {'source': {'data': [3, 4]}}, no duplication.

Comment: Okay so you want the same values even inside the lists not to be duplicated, just use a list(set()), see updated answer.

Comment: You hit the spot, m8! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value associated to the key and make the changes.
Lets take the dict example you have taken in your question:

```
x = {'name': 'Test', 'age': 23, 'channel': ['a'], 'source': {'data':   [1,2]}}
x['channel']=['a']
```

The value is of type list[].
you can append or add values to a list by list.append()

So, `x['channel'].append('c')` will give you:

```
{'age': 23, 'channel': ['a', 'c'], 'name': 'Test', 'source': {'data': [1, 2]}}
```

Comment: what about `'source'` ?

Comment: Just the extension of first case:

Comment: x['source']['data'].append()

Comment: and last case would be to just create a new key and its associated value     x['no']='xyz'